# creating login form

Tags: php, mysqli

while executing my code, getting error like

> Notice: Undefined index: username.

my query is not executing.

my code is as below:

```
include "connection.php";
mysqli_select_db($conn,"login");
$un=$_POST["username"];
$ps=$_POST["password"];

    $result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT username FROM login where username=$un" );   
    //$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if(!$result)
    {
        echo "error";
    }else{
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            if($row["username"]==$un && $row["password"]==$ps){
                echo "success";
            }else{
                echo "invalid";
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Please show us a code for a form. And read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: Use php isset when defining $un e $ps to get rid of the error. But this code will check the db if you are reaching this page from the form where you will enter username and password. The error says you are executing it without data coming from a form. Also your code is vulnerable to sql injection. At last, if you are a newbie, use Pdo and prepared statements instead of mysqli api

Comment: As you are just `a beginner` - try learning now to use `prepared statements`rather than embedding variables directly in the sql

Comment: Why are you using a loop to loop through username and password as for a login you just need to match one row for username and one for password so the while loop is not needed

Comment: <html>
<body>
<form action = "login_valid.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td> Username : <input type ="text" Name = "username" id="username"></td>

<td> Password : <input type ="Password" Name = "password" id="password"></td>

<td><input type= "submit" name="OK" value="submit"></td></tr>
</table>  

</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Also you are not checking if the session is set you should have a if (isset($un) && isset($ps)) and then continue with script execution

Comment: sorry, i am not able to understand, can you give me the example..? or show me by editing my code by correcting the mistakes i m doing

Answer (score 1):

```
include "connection.php"; 
mysqli_select_db($conn,"login");

if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
    $un=$_POST["username"];
    $ps= $_POST["password"];
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT username, password FROM login where username='".$un."'"); 
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
   if(!$result){ 
       echo "error";
   }else{ 
       if($row["username"]==$un && $row["password"]==$ps){
           echo "success";
       }else{
           echo "invalid"; 
       }
   }
}else{ 
    echo "You forgot to enter a username or password";
}
```

This is very rough idea of what I mean, there is other issues like it is vulnerable to sql injections and plain text passwords

Comment: You don't get rid of OP error with your code. You need to use `if(isset($_POST['username'])){$un=$_POST['username'];}else{echo "You didn't provide a username";}`

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, how did you execute the script? If you tried executing the script directly by pointing your browser to something like `http://localhost:8080/login.php` where `localhost:8080` is assumed to be your server amd `login.php` is assumed to be your login script, then you have made few mistakes.

To begin with, direct executions like the one mentioned above takes place as `GET` request. Whenever the client (browser) requests the server for a resource, it always issues a `GET` request. In that case, you can try something like `http://localhost:8080/login.php?username=root&password=root`

Then, in your script, as you are using `GET`, use `$_GET` global array. Something like

```
<?php
    var_dump($_GET['username']);
    var_dump($_GET['password']);
?>
```

Should show `root` as username and password.

As you can see, this is a very insecure idea. Your username and password is available in the wild. To reduce this, enter `POST`.

`POST` has more capacity (it can transfer more data) than `GET`. Also, the data transfered by `POST` is hidden (not available as query strings) as in the case of `GET`.

Before going further, create a simple login form like

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
</form>
```

and save it as `login.php` Now, you might have noticed that I have not mentioned the `action` attribute. This is because by default `action` attribute refers to the same page - which is exactly what we want.

Now, add the following to `login.php`

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST['username']);
    var_dump($_POST['password']);
?>
```

You might have noticed that the `name` attribute used for `input` elements in the form matches exactly with the keys used to access the `$_POST` global array. This is no coincidence. This is because the values send via `POST` request to the server is allocated in the `$_POST` global array based on the name to it using the `name` attribute.

Also, the `method` attribute of `form` element had to specified to `POST` because, as already mentioned, the browser uses `GET` to send requests to the server by default.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you replace the line

$result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT username, password FROM login where username=$un" );

with

$result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT username, password FROM login where username='".$un."'" );

ie. you don't want the 3 characters "$ u n" in your query text, but you want the contents of the variable $un as the text in your query.